# Meta-meta Site Policy on History.SE — FAQ

Tags: discussion, faq, site-policy, approved-site-policy

This is the central repository for how we do things on History.StackExchange.

This complements and extends our [Help-Centre](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/help), which is limited in space and slow to change.

## Welcome to new users

[FAQ: History:Stack Exchange](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/faq-historystack-exchange)

## General Site Policy

- [How do we determine site policy, how do we reach consensus about it?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-do-we-determine-site-policy-how-do-we-reach-consensus-about-it)

<sub>(Looks like we're on our own here [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/437864) But we might divert from the model set by SE and orient our policies along the lines of [Skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) or Academia?)</sub>

[Site policy for very heavily-trolled topics](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/site-policy-for-very-heavily-trolled-topics)

- [Holocaust/Nazi/WW2 trivia questions - what to do?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/holocaust-nazi-ww2-trivia-questions-what-to-do/3473#3473)
- [How to enforce much stronger standards for answers touching Nazi/Holocaust topics?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3867/how-to-enforce-much-stronger-standards-for-answers-touching-nazi-holocaust-topic)
- [How to deal with accepted answers that were sourced out of right-wing propaganda/conspiracy sites?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3319/1401)

[Are requests for references appropriate on History Stack Exchange?(revisited)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/are-requests-for-references-appropriate-on-history-stack-exchangerevisited)

[History of *what* exactly?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/history-of-what-exactly)

[Do we have or need a policy concerning publication of information which may involve living individuals?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/do-we-have-or-need-a-policy-concerning-publication-of-information-which-may-invo)

[Are recent political history questions on topic?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/are-recent-political-history-questions-on-topic)

[How can you tell "political questions" apart from "historical questions"?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/406/how-can-you-tell-political-questions-apart-from-historical-questions)

[What is History?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/540/what-is-history)

[Are questions about the history of politics on-topic here?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/are-questions-about-the-history-of-politics-on-topic-here)

[Is recent history on topic?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/is-recent-history-on-topic)

[Do questions about current events of historic significance belong here?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4333/do-questions-about-current-events-of-historic-significance-belong-here)

## On Asking Questions

[How much research should one do before asking a question?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567/how-much-research-should-one-do-before-asking-a-question)

[Etiquette of breaking down a large question into a series of smaller ones](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/etiquette-of-breaking-down-a-large-question-into-a-series-of-smaller-ones)

[How are questions migrated?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/how-are-questions-migrated)

[Wikipedia Versus S.E History](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91/wikipedia-versus-s-e-history)

[Is there a notability criterion or not?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3998/is-there-a-notability-criterion-or-not)

[FAQ: My question has been 'closed', what does it mean?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4055/faq-my-question-has-been-closed-what-does-it-mean)

[Are questions about hypothetical events off topic?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/are-questions-about-hypothetical-events-off-topic)

[How should H:SE deal with questions about race?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3828/how-should-hse-deal-with-questions-about-race)

[Requests for references](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/requests-for-references)

## On Writing Answers

[What is the typically preferred length of an HistorySE answer and what factors influence that?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/what-is-the-typically-preferred-length-of-an-historyse-answer-and-what-factors-i)

[Adding answers to old questions which already have good answers](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/adding-answers-to-old-questions-which-already-have-good-answers)

[Is it OK to answer old questions?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/is-it-ok-to-answer-old-questions)

## On Voting

[Why did my question get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-my-question-get-a-downvote)

[Why did I get an upvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/750/why-did-i-get-an-upvote)

[Why did my answer get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/why-did-my-answer-get-a-downvote)

[Is it OK to vote down on question when I just don't like the topic?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/is-it-ok-to-vote-down-on-question-when-i-just-dont-like-the-topic)

[+1 is *not* a 'traditional welcoming gift'](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346/1-is-not-a-traditional-welcoming-gift)

## On Commenting

[Standard comment situations: suggestions for close votes and down votes](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/standard-comment-situations-suggestions-for-close-votes-and-down-votes)

[Unanswered questions with answers or partial answers in comments](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3737/unanswered-questions-with-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments)

## On Flagging

[Can we flag answers because they lack sources?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/can-we-flag-answers-because-they-lack-sources)

- [Should we add more banners of the type 'citation needed'?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3947/should-we-add-more-banners-of-the-type-citation-needed)

[When should a comment be flagged?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/601/when-should-a-comment-be-flagged)

## On editing

[What's the policy on 'bump' edits?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/whats-the-policy-on-bump-edits)

[When are tag edits acceptable because the question is mis-tagged?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4119/when-are-tag-edits-acceptable-because-the-question-is-mis-tagged)

…

Comment: If this is seen as a good idea, please revise and expand. The list should become somewhat authoritative (and currently is not, for sure)…

Comment: Love it!  Makes it easier to find, discuss, agree on and reference our site norms.   Very good.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace there is a [meta-tag:faq] tag that can only be added by mods, if you think this question worths it :)

Comment: I do; I have;  I thank!

Comment: My only concern here is that this presents '_Site policy_' as if it is something that has already been agreed, whereas - in fact - we have yet to even figure out how we reach consensus in order to agree those policies!

Comment: @sempaiscuba We have to start somewhere… And I listed "#General Site Policy" with corresponding link and Q first on purpose. Alas, that seems to not have too much traction. If you see a more legitimate way of " Bootstrapping policy"?

Comment: No.  Like I said before, I don't have answers, only questions.  I think this question is a good start, but this is probably something that should have been tackled a long time ago.

Comment: I think we already have more than one 'sub-culture' here on History:SE.  At least one of those (based on observing some user votes in review queues) appears to be at variance with what most of us consider to be agreed site policy, for example, in terms of what questions are on-topic on this site..

Comment: @sempaiscuba Not sure I follow. (Going through that 'history' of reviews is often quite the puzzle for me, (concluding: *I* am quite at odds far too often). If you have insight of patterns or relationshjps between oddly UVs and strange matter reviews: I implore you to write an analysis of that (mods are allowed to do that? Wear your H:SE user-hat). In time, if need be. The chicken-egg-consensus thing is really sth *I* want to set down to go forward *before* editing this much further.

Comment: @LаngLаngС If people are voting to leave questions open, even when they are clearly off-topic, then that is at variance with what most of us consider to be agreed site policy, no?  If they are doing it regularly (which is, nevertheless, their right if they have sufficient reputation), then we clearly do not have universal agreement on '_Site policy_' even at that basic level.

Comment: Exactly. Except: do 'they' know, 'violating' on purpose, unknowingly, ignorant, or just 'own minded'? I think the ignorant part could and should be addressed by this thing  here. And the 'own.minded' about this should also be dragged in: voicing 'their' opinion,  in order to convince them otherwise, or documenting why 'some' deviate? "Clear" is opinion— I often agree with— but the main problem seems to me: what is what *I*(*you*) see as site policy, do I differ on site policy or *how to apply it*, or do I oppose site-policy?

Comment: In the case of close / reopen votes on review queues, I don't think that it's ignorance.  So it does appear we have 'sub-cultures' (it would probably be too  harsh to call them 'factions'). Beyond that, who knows?  Like I said, no answers. Just questions.  And things that should probably have been settled a long time ago.

Comment: I am just *the* sucker for hard data. Why not cal them factions in the explorative phase? I'd really like to take this beyond mere personal impressions, even SEDE queries I feel quite burned to appear on MSE on such a level, but  is there any mod channel I do not know to exploit for such an inquiry? (or if you have access to data I'm not privy to. I have theories on queues and voting, but they're ad-hoc, on data scarcity/sample bias).

Comment: If you want hard data, just copy and paste the page from the review queue into a spreadsheet (it's just a table).  Repeat for as many pages as you like and you have review data for that queue to analyse.  Depending on how you sort the data, you can look for robo-voting, 'factions' or 'sub-cultures' or whatever you want to call them, ('faction' implies a degree of organisation that is not evident imo), and even just participation in the review process.